# CustomScope may not reference bindings with different scopes

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am new to dagger, I have defined my application component like this

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(BaseActivity activity);
    Context context();
}
```

This is my ApplicationModule

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    public TipoApplication application;

    public ApplicationModule(TipoApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Context provideContext(){return application.getApplicationContext();}

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences(Context context){
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Gson provideGson(){
        return new Gson();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public SharedPrefsManager provideSharedPrefsManager(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, Gson gson){
        return new SharedPrefsManager(sharedPreferences, gson);
    }
}
```

I have created a dependent Component LocationProviderComponent

```
@LocationScope
@Component(dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class},modules = {LocationProviderModule.class})
public interface LocationProviderComponent {
    void inject(LocationRepository locationRepository);
}
```

And Finally My LocationProviderModule

```
@Module
public class LocationProviderModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    FusedLocationProviderClient provideFusedLocationProviderClient(Context context) {
        return LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);

    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    LocationRequest provideLocationRequest() {
        return new LocationRequest()
                .setInterval(5000)
                .setFastestInterval(60000)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    LocationSettingsRequest provideLocationSettingRequest(LocationRequest mLocationRequest) {
        return new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest).build();
    }

}
```

I am getting 2 errors when I build.

1st   cannot find symbol class DaggerApplicationComponent
2nd

```
LocationProviderComponent scoped with LocationScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
@Singleton @Provides FusedLocationProviderClient LocationProviderModule.provideFusedLocationProviderClient(android.content.Context)
@Singleton @Provides LocationRequest .module.LocationProviderModule.provideLocationRequest()
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Any module's `@Provides` method may only have the same scope as the component they are part of. Read more [here](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#scope).

In your case `LocationProviderModule` is part of the `LocationProviderComponent` which is scoped with `@LocationScope` whereas the provides methods in that module uses the `@Singleton` scope. This is exactly what Dagger is complaining about:

> LocationProviderComponent scoped with LocationScope may not reference
> bindings with different scopes

It is also pointing to where the problem is:

```
@Singleton @Provides FusedLocationProviderClient LocationProviderModule.provideFusedLocationProviderClient(android.content.Context)
@Singleton @Provides LocationRequest.module.LocationProviderModule.provideLocationRequest()
```

Instead of using `@Singleton`, you just need to use `@LocationScope` in the `LocationProviderModule`.

Comment: What if the FusedLocation is used as a singleton elsewhere?

Comment: Ah nvm, I just figured out, just included it at the App Component :p ez pc

Comment: In my case I wasn't mentioning Repo in AppComponent. So after adding to AppComponent, it worked

Comment: @desgraci App Component - which means it always lives and eats the memory while app process is alive